# External api management service can't resolve Azure function service name

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

Currently I am trying to use Api Management to expose an Azure Function http trigger that is within a vnet.

After setting everything up, I tried a simple GET request and I'm getting a 500 error telling me

```
    "messages": [
        "Error occured while calling backend service.",
        "The remote name could not be resolved: '<function-name>.azurewebsites.net'"
    ]
```

**My Azure function was:**

1. Created with a premium plan.
2. enabled inbound traffic with a private endpoint.
3. deployed in the same Vnet as my api management service.
4. Added a httpTrigger template from the portal
5. Was set up with a Azure managed DNS name

My api management service was created in external mode and I linked my function to Api Management in the portal.

**Things I've tried:**

- I've double checked that the correct security group rules have been opened for api management to work
- I've ensured that both my api management (external) is in the same vnet as my Serverless function
- I deployed a vm to the same virtual network and was unable to resolve the dns name of my function there. Used ping, telnet, nslookup.
- Tried adding application settings to my function to specify the azure dns server, among other settings.
- Ive check that my private dns zone is linked with my vnet.

Seems like a DNS name resolving issue, but I can't seem to fix it. Any ideas on what could be causing this error?

**update**

So it seems to be an issue with my private endpoint. Every function I create without one works fine, but I would still like to have the private endpoint so it isn't accessible from the internet.

I know I could probably lockdown my function to only be called from the api management gateway ip, but I would rather not have to hard code IPs if I don't have too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [MayankBargali-MSFT | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/mayankbargali-msft/) Posting your suggestion as answer to help other community members.

> As per the error, the APIM is not able to resolve your azure function
> app. Can you please verify if the custom DNS is correctly setup and
> you can refer to [this
> document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet?tabs=stv2#custom-dns-server-setup)
> for more details. Outbound access on **port 53** is required for
> communication with DNS servers. If a custom DNS server exists on the
> other end of a VPN gateway, the DNS server must be reachable from the
> subnet hosting API Management. I will also suggest you to review [this
> document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#name-resolution-that-uses-your-own-dns-server) for the setup part.

Reference: [External api management service can't resolve Azure function service name - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/748424/external-api-management-service-can39t-resolve-azu.html)